# Cannot interrupt mpg123 when using an audio output buffer (--buffer)

Tags: audio, arm, freeze, application, streaming

#### Background

I am streaming Internet radio using `mpg123` on PocketC.H.I.P. This is the command I use:

```
sudo mpg123-alsa \
  --aggressive --realtime \
  -a hw:1,0 \
  -v \
  --no-icy-meta \
  --preload 0.5 \
  http://176.9.138.209:8025/dfm_1
```

The playback is smooth for most time but sometimes it stops for a few seconds. I thought that adding a buffer might fix this issue so I added `--buffer 1024` to the above command.

As a result, `mpg123` printed that it loaded 7 seconds of frames (which is around the size of the buffer) and stopped. No audio is playing and the program is not responding to SIGINT (^C). I have to kill it with `kill`.

## Question

Why does adding an audio output buffer (*using the `-b` argument*) break `mpg123`?

---

#### Further Details

- I am using mpg123 1.20.1